# What is the yellow drink Jennifer Lawrence had in Mother!?

Tags: mother

In the movie *Mother!*, Jennifer Lawrence kept drinking a golden colour drink that looks like the powder she used to paint the walls in the beginning of the movie.

When she got pregnant she threw the powder in the toilet.

I wonder what does it represent?